# How to read (decode) tfrecords with tf.data API

Tags: tensorflow

I have a custom dataset, that I then stored as tfrecord, doing

```
# toy example data
label = np.asarray([[1,2,3],
                    [4,5,6]]).reshape(2, 3, -1)

sample = np.stack((label + 200).reshape(2, 3, -1))

def bytes_feature(values):
    """Returns a TF-Feature of bytes.
    Args:
    values: A string.
    Returns:
    A TF-Feature.
    """
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[values]))


def labeled_image_to_tfexample(sample_binary_string, label_binary_string):
    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'sample/image': bytes_feature(sample_binary_string),
      'sample/label': bytes_feature(label_binary_string)
    }))


def _write_to_tf_record():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        image_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.uint16)
        encoded_image = tf.image.encode_png(image_placeholder)

        label_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.uint16)
        encoded_label = tf.image.encode_png(image_placeholder)

        with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("./toy.tfrecord") as writer:
            with tf.Session() as sess:
                feed_dict = {image_placeholder: sample,
                             label_placeholder: label}

                # Encode image and label as binary strings to be written to tf_record
                image_string, label_string = sess.run(fetches=(encoded_image, encoded_label),
                                                      feed_dict=feed_dict)

                # Define structure of what is going to be written
                file_structure = labeled_image_to_tfexample(image_string, label_string)

                writer.write(file_structure.SerializeToString())
                return
```

However I cannot read it. First I tried (based on http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html ,  https://medium.com/coinmonks/storage-efficient-tfrecord-for-images-6dc322b81db4 and https://medium.com/mostly-ai/tensorflow-records-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-c46bc4bbb564)

```
def read_tfrecord_low_level():
    data_path = "./toy.tfrecord"
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, raw_records = reader.read(filename_queue)

    decode_protocol = {
        'sample/image': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
        'sample/label': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64)
    }
    enc_example = tf.parse_single_example(raw_records, features=decode_protocol)
    recovered_image = enc_example["sample/image"]
    recovered_label = enc_example["sample/label"]

    return recovered_image, recovered_label
```

I also tried variations casting enc_example and decoding it, such as in [Unable to read from Tensorflow tfrecord file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809776/unable-to-read-from-tensorflow-tfrecord-file) However when I try to evaluate them my python session just freezes and gives no output or traceback.

Then I tried using eager execution to see what is happening, but apparently it is only compatible with tf.data API. However as far as I understand transformations on tf.data API are made on the whole dataset. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data mentions that a decode function must be written, but doesn't give an example on how to do that. All the tutorials I have found are made for TFRecordReader (which doesn't work for me).

Any help (pinpointing what I am doing wrong/ explaining what is happening/ indications on how to decode tfrecords with tf.data API) is highly appreciated.

According to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oNdaQk0Qv4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIcqeP7MFH0 tf.data is the best way to create input pipelines, so I am highly interested on learning that way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why storing the encoded png causes the evaluation to not work, but here is a possible way of working around the problem. Since you mentioned that you would like to use the `tf.data` way of creating input pipelines, I'll show how to use it with your toy example:

```
label = np.asarray([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6]]).reshape(2, 3, -1)

sample = np.stack((label + 200).reshape(2, 3, -1))
```

First, the data has to be saved to the TFRecord file. The difference from what you did is that the image is not encoded to png.

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
     return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("toy.tfrecord")

example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'label_raw': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(label.tostring())),
             'sample_raw': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(sample.tostring()))}))

writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
```

What happens in the code above is that the arrays are turned into strings (1d objects) and then stored as bytes features.

Then, to read the data back using the `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` and `tf.data.Iterator` class:

```
filename = 'toy.tfrecord'

# Create a placeholder that will contain the name of the TFRecord file to use
data_path = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, name="tfrecord_file")

# Create the dataset from the TFRecord file
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(data_path)

# Use the map function to read every sample from the TFRecord file (_read_from_tfrecord is shown below)
dataset = dataset.map(_read_from_tfrecord)

# Create an iterator object that enables you to access all the samples in the dataset
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
label_tf, sample_tf = iterator.get_next()

# Similarly to tf.Variables, the iterators have to be initialised
iterator_init = iterator.make_initializer(dataset, name="dataset_init")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialise the iterator passing the name of the TFRecord file to the placeholder
    sess.run(iterator_init, feed_dict={data_path: filename})

    # Obtain the images and labels back
    read_label, read_sample = sess.run([label_tf, sample_tf])
```

The function `_read_from_tfrecord()` is:

```
def _read_from_tfrecord(example_proto):
        feature = {
            'label_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'sample_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }

    features = tf.parse_example([example_proto], features=feature)

    # Since the arrays were stored as strings, they are now 1d 
    label_1d = tf.decode_raw(features['label_raw'], tf.int64)
    sample_1d = tf.decode_raw(features['sample_raw'], tf.int64)

    # In order to make the arrays in their original shape, they have to be reshaped.
    label_restored = tf.reshape(label_1d, tf.stack([2, 3, -1]))
    sample_restored = tf.reshape(sample_1d, tf.stack([2, 3, -1]))

    return label_restored, sample_restored
```

Instead of hard-coding the shape `[2, 3, -1]`, you could also store that too into the TFRecord file, but for simplicity I didn't do it.

I made a little [gist](https://gist.github.com/SilviaAmAm/61fe0649a779545fec58134fb142bbe5) with a working example.

Hope this helps!